# Php shell_execute not working

Tags: php, sh, shell-exec

I have a problem that i can't to shell_exec(), but it just won't work. Is there a problem whit shell_exec() or it just cant run myfile.sh somehow.. 
If i run code in shell it works fine. My php wont run in safe mode, i did check it from php.ini file and i did check disable_functions aswell.
My php code returns right now just null.  And i did try also for testing purpose :

```
$result = exec('myfile.sh', $output, $status);
```

i got :

```
array(0){}int(127)
```

Both files have chmod 775 read and execute premissions.
I have file message.php what looks like

```
<?php
$user = "username";
$pass = "pass";
$from = "from who";
$to = "1234567";
$msg = "test message";

$host="https://web.myurl.ee:portnr/etc/etc";
$handle = curl_init($host);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_exec($handle);
$res = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

if($res >= 400){
    exit;
}else if($res < 200){
    exit;
}else{
    if(function_exists('shell_exec') && !ini_get('safe_mode')){
         $file = 'myfile.sh';
         if(file_exists($file)){
              $result = shell_exec($file ."$user $pass $from $to $msg");
              var_dump($result);
         }else{
            echo "No files";
         }
    }else{
        echo "check status";
    }
}
?>
```

and myfile.sh file looks like

```
#!/bin/sh
if [$# -ne 5 ]; then
    echo"jahas"
    exit 1
fi
etc...
```

What i miss here, any tips what to look or what to do for next.

In code can be some mistypes, i didn't copy paste it.

Comment: From where you are calling message.php, couldn't find any statement in sh file?

Comment: message.php is getting called manualy atm/just reload page and myfile.sh shold get all params.

Comment: Have you tried using full path to *myfile.sh*? The shell script is not going to get executed just because it's in the same directory as the calling PHP script.

Comment: Yes, bot are at same directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things to check here:

1. First determine if exec and shell_exec are disabled in php.ini

   disable_functions = exec
2. exex() accepts commands and no files if i am not mistaken so instead of simply adding the file name you should try:

   exec(dirname(**FILE**) . '/myfile.sh');

Using the  right directory and actually passing a command and not a file name.

Comment: I did check from php.ini: safe mode was off and disable_functions was empty.  I cant use exec, becouse i need to pass parameters aswell.

Comment: did you pass an actual command to exec? Ensuring that the directory is ok?

Comment: Did you mean exec('sh ./myfile.sh'); ?  It returns string(0)""

Comment: Now are you sure the directory is set correctly? Try this for example: exec(dirname('myfile.sh') . '/myfile.sh'); and put myfile.sh in the same directory with this script for example.

Comment: Both files are at same directory and i did shell_exec(`__DIR__`."/myfile.sh") but still same.

Comment: Yeah i did want to type it, ty :)

Comment: What PHP version are you using?

Comment: Everything seem ok there? do you use var_dump on the actual function return value as per your example, because then 0 means it  executed successfuly?

Comment: exec('sh ./myfile.sh'); returned 0, as per your comment? If that is correct it means it executed succesfully

Comment: It did retrurns string(0)""

Comment: Then it means as i said, that it executes successfully.  Thus the commands are invoked...

Comment: That means there is no problem with exec or shell_exec, your problems lies elsewhere // and i can not think of anything else for the moment.

Comment: Create, now i'm atleast one step closer for a solution. Ty alot!

Comment: I did try execute my message.php file in shell and it says : sh: user/local/safe: no such file or directory. I did run myfile.sh and it did work well. What it means, my sh file shold be in  usr/local/safe/myfile.sh ?

Comment: Is this the actual line you are using now? $result = shell_exec($file ."$user $pass $from $to $msg");

Comment: Atm i have $result = exec(`__DIR__` ."/ myfile.sh  '".$user."' '".$pass."' '".$from."' '".$to."' '".$msg."');

Comment: you have a space before the filename, is this the exact code you use? You should really be careful with spaces there.

Comment: Dunno mate this is a problem with the actual command, i can not think of anything specific, but if i was in your place and i was sure that the directory and command are correct, i would check that the user access to the file and folder. Other than that i have no idea what it might be.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either an absolute path or a relative path. For relative paths, the current directory is usually the PHP files's. If you can't access your scripts even with an absolute path, there could be a problem with filesystem access rights. Keep in mind PHP scripts are typically executed as the web server's (system) user account.

Your shell scripts should be stored somewhere near or inside your application tree, so that you can grant acces to them to your PHP scripts (i.e. to your web server), without compromising too much your file system security.